# Remove first and last gridline on CorePlot graph

Tags: ios, graph, core-plot, gridlines

Is there any way to delete first and last gridline on CorepLot graph?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `labelExclusionRanges` on the y-axis. This is an array of plot ranges that should be skipped when drawing tick marks and grid lines.